# How to achieve Gradient Fills in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, symbology

Does anyone know of a native way to achieve the gradient fills like the ones in the attached picture (map_1)?

The circular and rectangular fills that I see already in ArcGIS' symbology choices don't seem to take the whole polygon into consideration (map_2).

Is this type of thing done using another software package like Photoshop?

[image: map_1]

[image: map_2]

Comment: I notice these gradients have a circular fill. Have you tried changing it to buffered in the symbology dialog?

Comment: Do you just want the gradient effects in map 1? Or do you want the shadow/halo effects as well? The shadow effects have a Photoshop look to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you could accomplish it like this?
[image: GradientFillSymbol]